# css absolute position submit button bottom right corner not working

Tags: html, css, css-position

For some reason it positions the button outside of the div, just above the top right corner. It's as if just above the top right corner of the div is acting just like the bottom right corner.

if i add bottom 10px, for example, it will start above the div and move it up 10px. The same thing happens with right

**CSS:**

```
        #newSignupContent {
            display: block;
            position: relative;

            width: 400px;
            height: 250px;
            margin: auto auto;
        }

        #newSignupContent label {
            display: inline-block;
            float: left;
            clear: left;
            width: 40%;
            padding-right: 10px;

            text-align: right;
            color: white;
            font-family:calibri, Times, serif;
            font-size: 22px;

        }

        #newSignupContent input {
            display: inline-block;
            width: 50%;
            float: left;
            padding: 5px 10px 5px 0px;
        }

        #newSignupContent #newSignupSubmit {
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 0;
            right: 0;

            width: 80px;
            height: 40px;

            padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
        }
```

**Form:**

```
 <div id="newSignupContent">
                    <form action="/webroot/NewUserSignUpProcess" method="post">

                        <label>Account Name:</label>
                        <input type="text" name="txtAccountName">

                        <label>Email Address:</label>
                        <input type="text" name="txtEmailAddress">

                        <label>Password:</label>
                        <input type="text" name="txtPassword">

                        <input id="newSignupSubmit" type="submit" value="Submit">

                    </form>
                </div>
```

Comment: Do you have more CSS or a reset that could be affecting this? Unable to reproduce as shown in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NPeG8/

Comment: just a * {position: relative; padding: 0}

Comment: I stripped out all the outside divs to test. It doesn't make sense because I've used this same setup before and it worked just fine.

Comment: oh and i'm testing on firefox

Comment: OK i figured it out. For some reason it has something to do with the form element. If I move the form outside the outer div, it works fine

Answer (score 1):

Because of the `* {position:relative;}` you had there, your button position it self relatively to the '`form`' element. The '`form`' element, had no height, because all of its descendants had '`float:left;`' and thus didn't "stretch" the form's height. The '`submit`' button, positioned at '`bottom:0;right:0;`' relative to the form, which had no height, resulted in what looked like the top right corner of the containing '`div`'.

In the attached <kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ronency/KBrFV/1/)</kbd>, notice that if you remove the '`position:relative;`' form the '`form`' element, everything sets up right.
I also added borders to the containing '`div`' and to the '`form`'.